# Can we break a slide in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer  class to design my Quiz Programme. I used link for the  questions in a round in a single slide. 
Link is properly working when i am using mouse and when I press arrow key it takes to the next slide which contains the question.

**My Need**

(1) I need to put a break in my first page which should not allow to go to the next slide by simply clicking(whereas I have to use my Link button).

(2) May I define link for my click also?? Means 
    When I complete my Round 1 in the quiz, The next click must take me
    to the Round 2.

The screen shot below is my Round1 main page, the figure are the links to the questions and each question i have a go back button to come back round1 main page.
[image]

Comment: Beamer slides are just pages in a PDF, and your PDF reader controls how mouse clicks and keypresses are handled. Since you already have all the links in place, it'd probably be easiest to just insert one or more blank pages between your round 1 slide and the linked question slides.